# Do Duelist's Flurry and Sneak Attack stack?

Tags: dnd-4e, rogue, sneak-attack

[Duelist's Flurry](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=10165):

> Hit: Dexterity modifier damage, slide the target 1 square, and you shift 1 square. You may use your **sneak attack damage** even if you do not have combat advantage with this attack.

If I attack with combat advantage, can I perform a normal sneak attack as well as using the sneak attack damage?

When can I add the Brutal Scoundrel's bonus damage to this attack?

Comment: In the future, Kai, please come to chat so that we may help you with your posts. They contain significant errors. Otherwise, I've edited your question for grammar, spelling, and updated the power to match the most recent errata.

Comment: Ok. Thx for help

Comment: Please use proper English here, Kai. Those extra 2 keystrokes really do help comprehension. We are happy to help you polish your questions in chat, and can even source some foreign language natives.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Sneak attack damage" refers to the damage from your sneak attack. They are the same thing. All the Duelist's Flurry at-will does to your sneak attack, is let you apply the damage even when you don't have combat advantage.

Therefore:

**1. No,** since that would mean you added your sneak attack damage twice.

**2. Yes**, since the strength modifier is always passively included in a brutal scoundrel's sneak attack damage.